# Find term with multiple words from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So I'm doing a project where I'm finding words from a file, and then checking to see if it is in the dictionary. I don't know if I'm following the proper syntax because it prints out the else statement that it doesn't find "does not work" in dictionary.
Does it have anything to do with the spaces in between?

## test for term with multiple words -- does not work: -3

```
if 'does not work' in dictionary:
    expected_value3 = str(-3)
    actual_value3 = dictionary['does not work']
    if actual_value3 == expected_value3:
        print "---------------------------------"
        print "words with spaces passes| word: does not work"
    else:
        print "---------------------------------"
        print "words with spaces FALSE| word: does not work"
else:
    print "---------------------------------"
    print "does not work not in dictionary"
```

Comment: What does `dictionary` look like?

Comment: If `'does not work'` is not in `dictionary`, then your code is working correctly.  How do you create `dictionary`?  Can you show us what is inside?  Try `print dictionary` right before this if statement, it will show you what is inside.

Comment: no, does not work is an actual key inside of the dictionary

Comment: @Haidro , the dictionary is just a huge list of words and values.

Comment: Is 'does not work' in the dictionary as 'does not work'?  Or, is the case different, or are the spaces different?  That makes a difference.

Comment: @user2712870 Post a small portion of dict in the question body.

Comment: @SethMMorton , 'does not work' is the exact way that the text is written in the file.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, how do I make the code look all nice?

Comment: The reason I asked is because of this statement in your question: "Does it have anything to do with the spaces in between?"  What did you mean by that?  What spaces?

Comment: @user2712870 if a definition is like `does not work the operation did not complete successfully`, where `does not work` is the 'word' and `the operation did not complete successfully` is the def you *can't* just split by spaces, it's probably tab seperated so you `.split('\t')`

Comment: I meant that if having anything between two separate words would throw  when checking in the dictionary would throw off the program.

Comment: You keep deleting the code that shows how `dictionary` is created... can you post it in the question itself.  I think this is important for us to know.

Comment: You want to compare two strings, str(-3) with dictionary['does not work'], just make sure that the latter is a string type as well and you shouldn't have problems

Comment: dictionary = {}
    
    #TODO: INSERT YOUR CODE HERE. You will need a for loop\
    for line in scores_file:\
        sentiments = line.split()\
        dictionary[sentiments[0]] = sentiments[1]\ scores_file is just the text file

Comment: How can a key be `does not work` (note the spaces), yet you call `str.split()`?

Answer (score 1):

To deal with *phrases* you can't split a line in the dictionary file of the format `word def` by spaces because `word` might be made up of several words with spaces in-between. You need to have a character which won't appear in `word` or `def` to separate them, for instance a tab `\t` or pipe `|`, and then build your dictionary like so:

```
d = {}
with open('dict.txt') as df:
    for line in df:
        word,definition = line.split('\t')
        d[word] = definition
```

Otherwise you end up with

```
sentiments = ['does','not','work','the','operation',...]
```

In your loop, and you end up setting

```
dictionary['does'] = 'not'
```

With the code

```
for line in scores_file:
    sentiments = line.split()
    dictionary[sentiments[0]] = sentiments[1]
```

Comment: When I run the program, it doesn't do that. It just collects 'does not work' together, then sets the number following it to the value. The .txt file is: word, int, word, int, etc.

Comment: @user2712870 then you will want to split by `", "`, and then go `d[word] = int(definition)`

Comment: @user2712870 Please, for future questions, post *all* relevant information needed to solve the problem.  In this case, the relevant information is what is in the text file, and how you parse the text file to generate the dictionary.